# DFS on undirected graph?

Tags: java, depth-first-search

I am working on a undirected friendship graph which consists of students who are friends at a particular school. I want to get cliques(all connected subgraphs from the graph) using dfs. But for some reason my dfs is not working correctly.. Any suggestions on the algorithm or the code is appreciated

this is a sample graph created manually..

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;


public class DFS {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    class Node {

        String personName, schoolName;
        Node next;

        public Node(String personName, String schoolName, Node next) {

            this.personName = personName;
            this.schoolName = schoolName;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public String toString() {

            return this.personName + " " + this.schoolName;

        }

    }

    public Node[] build() {

        Node[] graph = new Node[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {

            Node temp = new Node(Integer.toString(i + 1), "MIT", null);
            graph[i] = temp;

        }

        graph[0].next = new Node("2", "MIT", null);

        graph[1].next = new Node("1", "MIT", null);
        graph[1].next.next = new Node("3", "MIT", null);
        graph[1].next.next.next = new Node("4", "MIT", null);

        graph[2].next = new Node("2", "MIT", null);
        graph[2].next.next = new Node("4", "MIT", null);

        graph[3].next = new Node("3", "MIT", null);
        graph[3].next.next = new Node("2", "MIT", null);    

        graph[4].next = new Node("6", "MIT", null);
        graph[5].next = new Node("5", "MIT", null);

        printGraph(graph);

        return graph;

    }

    public void dfsDriver() {

        Node[] graph = build();

        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> names = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {

            if (graph[i] != null) {

                names.put(graph[i].personName, count);

                count++;
            }               
        }

        boolean[] visited = new boolean[graph.length];

        for (int v = 0; v < visited.length; v++) {

            visited[v] = false;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {

            if (graph[i] != null) {

                if (!visited[i]) {

                        System.out.println("Starting at " + graph[i].personName);

                        dfs(i, visited, names, graph);                      
                }               
            }               
        }

    }

    private void dfs(int i, boolean[] visited, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> names, Node[] subGraph) {

        visited[i] = true;

        for (Node e = subGraph[i].next; e != null; e = e.next) {

            System.out.println("visiting " + e.personName);

            int index = names.get(e.personName);

            if (!visited[index]) {

                dfs(index, visited, names, subGraph);

            }           
        }

    }   

    public void printGraph(Node[] list) {

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

            if (list[i] != null) {

                System.out.print(list[i]);

                for (Node a = list[i].next; a != null; a = a.next) {

                    System.out.print(" " + a);

                }

                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DFS a = new DFS();

        a.dfsDriver();

    }

}
```

Comment: can u specifically point out where did u find the wrong behavior in the output ? what did u expect ?

Comment: actually this is just test program.. my real program crashes as its not able to go through the graph correctly.. u want to test that code out for me and help me out i would really appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

**#1 : The graph creation is inefficient.**
See this method in your code:

```
public Node[] build() {
```

There are 6 nodes that you wanted and look how many times are you calling "`new Node`". Its 6 + 10 times..Try to modify your data structures so that they suit to the inputs.
The current DS is :

```
class Node {
    String personName, schoolName;
    Node next;
```

Think about modifying this so that each node can "point" to multiple other nodes without creating new object for its frends every time.

**#2 Confusing print statement in dfs method()**

It should be like this:

```
private void dfs(int i, boolean[] visited, 
                 LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> names, Node[] subGraph) {
    visited[i] = true;
    for (Node e = subGraph[i].next; e != null; e = e.next) {
        int index = names.get(e.personName);
        if (!visited[index]) {
            System.out.println("visiting " + e.personName);
            dfs(index, visited, names, subGraph);
        }           
    }
}
```

**#3: There is no mechanism to store the end results**

You want all connected subgraphs from the main graph. However I dont see any provision to store/ mark the graph. You can modify the 2nd `for loop` inside `public void dfsDriver()` method so that it will create a new graph from the NEW nodes visited after each iteration.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question.

Comment: @BartKiers: work in progress. i am posting things in small snippets...see #2,#3